# use variable in mailto hyperlink in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to use a variable declared in my .cs page(C#) as cc to mailto, but dont know how to use. Please help.

```
In default.aspx.cs page:
var code=cc@test.com;

In default.aspx page:


<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="mailto:to@test.com?subject=Hi&cc=code" ToolTip="Submit" Target="_blank">mail</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to do this but you can set the `NavigateUrl` from code behind.

Try this:

```
HyperLink5.NavigateUrl="mailto:to@test.com?subject=Hi&cc="+code;
```

Comment: Please post the entire tag.

Comment: You should put this code after var code=cc@test.com line and in your markup file <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="" ToolTip="Submit" Target="_blank">mail</asp:HyperLink>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embeding code like

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="mailto:to@test.com?subject=Hi&cc="<%=code%> ToolTip="Submit" Target="_blank">mail</asp:HyperLink>
```